# how to import http test script to jmeter from RPT

Tags: import, export, jmeter, rpt

is it possible to convert to jmx the http test scenarios prepared in RPT, and exported to some intermediate fomat, by using some free tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no obvious RPT to JMeter converter, however you can get at least test "skeleton" using JMeter's recording functionality.

1. Configure [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) and start JMeter proxy. The easiest way to get "good" working configuration is using [JMeter Template feature](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   - launch JMeter
   - from the top menu click File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create
   - select Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
   - Click "Start" button

[image: JMeter Proxy Server]

2. Configure RPT to use host running JMeter as a proxy. In order to do so:

   - Right click at "Connection" object in Test Contents
   - Add -> Proxy
   - Provide host running JMeter and port 8888 as "Host" and "Port"

[image: RPT Proxy Settings]

3. Start your load test (better with 1 virtual user and 1 iteration) in the RPT
4. JMeter should be recording the requests.

Comment: Good idea, thanks! I mean, I was hoping for something that would be capable of transferring more, if not everything, but I too think that was a little bit naive, this sounds like a maximum I could hope for.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be any tool to do so.

Maybe you can give more details on the RPT script format by showing a sample, this would give some ideas.

Comment: This is a good answer too, thanks UBIK LOAD PACK. You can get the idea of how things work with RPT here:

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21625767. All file extensions described there are unfortunately not text files (hence, not actually scripts). However, there appear to be some text files in ./src/test subfolders of the workspace, that have an extension .oldrtpversion, but I don't think they could be suitable. Although I had intention to provide some samples, after removing the sensitive data from them, I really cannot do that.

Comment: Correction, obviously some of them are text files (for example .java source files), but things like data correlation and data pooling cannot be easily transferred to jmeter. So, it must be done manually, after the procedure proposed by Dmitri.