# Converting VSTS web tests to JMeter scripts

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops

We have web performance tests (scripts) developed in Visual Studio 2017 for load testing.  Now the requirement has come to replace VSTS and have JMeter for load testing.

I want to avoid developing scripts in JMeter from scratch and for that I'm looking for a way to convert VS web tests to JMeter scripts. Even if it's converting to other extension like .har and then to .jmx (JMeter), that's fine. There are online tools from BlazeMeter and others but our scripts are confidential and that's why I'm looking for a desktop solution.

I read somewhere that fiddler exports to .jmx, but I couldn't find that.

Answer (score 0):

> Converting VSTS web tests to JMeter scripts

If you are looking for a simple solution that is free to converte web tests to JMeter scripts, you can record the scripts by using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder:

Check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284190/how-to-import-http-test-script-to-jmeter-from-rpt) in this thread for some more details.

Besides, Shravan Akula provided a project to convert http/html scripts to jmeter:

https://github.com/ShravanAkula/LR_Jmeter_Converter

If possible, you can check if it works for you.

Hope this helps.